# Counting associations in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, associations, aggregate-functions

I have two models, `User` and `Group`, where groups contain many users. If I want to count the number of users in each group using a single query, I can use the following SQL:

```
select id, (select count(1) from users where group_id = groups.id) from groups
```

Is it possible to do this efficiently with ActiveRecord?

To be clear, this query will list all group ids, along with the number of users in each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either to get count

1. using associations

   ```
   group = Group.find(1) #find group with id = 1
   group.users.count    # count users whose group_id = 1 calls db everytime
    or  
   group.users.size  # get size from cache if group.users loaded
   ```
2. or directly

   ```
   User.where(:group_id=>1).count
   ```

count helper fires a count(*) query on the database with specified conditions
check more options at 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count

also I recommend you to go through [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I was unclear, I am wondering how to get this count for all groups at once.

Answer (score 0):

I found an efficient solution using a join:

```
Group.all(
  :select => "groups.id, count(u.group_id) as users_count",
  :joins  => "LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.group_id = groups.id",
  :group  => "groups.id"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution is simply translate your query to ActiveRecord and use the subquery:

```rb
subquery = User.where("users.group_id = groups.id").select('count(1)')
groups_with_count = Group.select(:id, "(#{subquery.to_sql}) as users_count")
```

Or use a sql grouping for the same result

```rb
groups_with_count = Group.joins(:users).select(:id, 'count(users.id) as users_count').group(:id)
```

in both case you can now have the result in ONE query with MINIMAL raw sql:

```rb
groups_with_count.each { |group| puts "#{group.id} => #{group.users_count}" }
```

---

#### Additional note

You can write the first subquery as `subquery = User.via(:group).select('count(1)')` which is more simple and maintainable imo, by using the following helper.

I've used this code on several projects in order to write nicer subquery:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    # transform Raw sql that references an association such as: Shift.where('shifts.id = checkins.shift_id')
    # into a simpler version Shift.via(:checkin) if shift have the checkin relationship
    # No support for polymorphic association
    # Basic support for "through" reflection (using join)
    def via(name)
        association = reflect_on_association(name)

        raise ArgumentError, "#{name} is not a valid association of #{self.class.name}" unless association
        raise NotImplementedError if association.polymorphic?

        join_keys = association.join_keys
        table_column = arel_table[join_keys.foreign_key]
        association_column = Arel::Table.new(association.table_name)[join_keys.key]

        if association.through_reflection?
            through_association = association.through_reflection
            table_column = Arel::Table.new(through_association.table_name)[join_keys.foreign_key]

            joins(through_association.name).where(table_column.eq(association_column))
        else
            where(table_column.eq(association_column))
        end
    end
end
```